# Change default xib view in xCode 4.5 to 3.5" and not 4"

Tags: view, size, default, xib, xcode4.5

Since updating to xCode 4.5, and with the release of the iPhone 5 with the 4" display, each time I create a new ViewController with a xib file, the xib defaults to a 4" display size.

At the moment I'm working through Aaron Hillegass's excellent iOS Programming text. All the examples assume a 3.5" Xib.  How do I get new views to be 3.5" instead of the taller skinny 4" default xib views?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here:

[How to make a uitableview in interface builder compatible with a 4 inch iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406505/how-to-make-a-uitableview-in-interface-builder-compatible-with-a-4-inch-iphone)

there is a 'Size' option in the view's attribute inspector that I somehow didn't see before.  Picking the 'Retina 3.5 Full Screen' option sets the xib view back to the old 3.5" size.

...Dale