# Can you set default nib size to 3.5" in xCode 4.5.1?

Tags: xcode, view, size, default, nib

Ever since updating xCode to the latest version (v. 4.5.1) every time I create a new nib or storyboard it assumes a default view size of 4" (ie: to reflect the new iPhone 5). However, I'm working through many tutorials and text books as I'm learning Objective C and they all use 3.5" view sizes.  I know how to go in and change view size back to 3.5 inch (as per my prior post/question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750862/change-default-xib-view-in-xcode-4-5-to-3-5-and-not-4)), but I'm wondering if there is a way in xCode to set 3.5 as the permanent default view size every time I create a new nib/storyboard. I looked around and there is no obvious method. I'm really getting tired of having to set nib/views to 3.5" over and over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

if your interface is using Storyboard:

Open *.Storyboard with "Text Editor"

and go the end bottom & find 
`<simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" type="retina4"/>`

delete 
`type="retina4"`

then it will be default size in 3.5"

if not Storyboard, it's using Xib
maybe you should edit each file. 
[How to make a uitableview in interface builder compatible with a 4 inch iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406505/how-to-make-a-uitableview-in-interface-builder-compatible-with-a-4-inch-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

In a xib, if you click the main view, you can choose the size there, in the simulated metrics. And in storyboard the same, you select a viewController and you can choose the size in simulated metrics

Comment: Thanks jcesar. Yes, I know that. As per my prior post/question that I referenced. I'm looking for some kind of xCode-wide default, or maybe even a Project-wide default. I tried setting a project's Deployment Target to iOS 5 and the xib defaults were STILL 4" even though iOS 5 doesn't support 4" views. I'm setting up many xibs each day as I go through tutorials, I'd rather not have to change the size of every single xib every time I create one. I'm hoping there is some development setting somewhere that I can set xCode's default to 3.5" instead of its current default of 4". :)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such option. I have an old project, and it creates the xibs with 3,5", but all my new projects create the xibs with 4". Furthermore, you have to remove the autolayout option of all of your xibs.

Comment: Yupp, it took me awhile to figure that (disabling autolayout) out too.  Thanks jcesar. I hope we both missed something and some smart person will point us in the right direction :)